# Check script running by Apache by PID

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

Via `HTOP` I detect some Apache scripts running (`www-data /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`) for a long time, or even using a lot of CPU.

In some cases these scripts are the cause of database congestion and/or slow apache server, creating a ripple effect that leaves our systems sluggish or in the worst case, unavailable for use.

I know Apache has `mod_status`, but the [CIS Benchmarks](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/) recommendation is to disable this feature for security, in order to prevent intruders from being able to view this information.

Is it possible via PID to find out which script on my site this process is running?

Comment: like `ps --ppid PID` to select all chlid from PID ? (on a side note, nothing show up on apache's log ? I would seek for misspelled/undeclared php variable for instance)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is EOL. Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.

Comment: @Archemar The number of requests in the log is huge, even per minute, making it impossible to track anything. It also does not record the PID that generated the request.